# How can I exclude an ES6 module (VueJS) from treeshaking in RollupJS? (and should I?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollupjs

Right now I pull in all my own es6 modules and create a bundle using Rollup.

Recently I started using VueJS, which now has an ES6 Module which can be pulled in just like my own modules. Rollup does some treeshaking on it, but I don't know if that is a very good idea? I don't know what it is doing, so I would rather it does nothing!

Instead I just add vue at the end of my HTML:

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

I love the convenience of having everything as one bundled file, but should I really treeshake the entire Vue app, is there a command in Rollup that I can not treeshake just this one module?

EDIT

I have found the --external option, which seems good as it would just keep the `import` for vue and bundle the rest, but it does not seem to work!

When I use `rollup --format=iife --external=../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js --file=dist/bundle.js -- src/main.js` it says `Error: Could not resolve '../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js' from src/app.js`.

In my main.js it has `import Vue from '../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js;` which works fine for the app. I want to make Vue an external, but it won't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent Rollup from treeshaking a particular module, you can simply import it blindly (instead of a part of it), so that Rollup thinks the module performs some side effect:

```
import 'vue'
```

Of course you can still import some bits in parallel, so that you can rename the default export for example:

```
import 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
```

As for your `--external` option, you probably just need to wrap the path value with quotes:

```
--external='../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'
```

Note that you should probably switch to Rollup configuration file (instead of CLI options) to make your life easier. You will also be able to use rollup plugins, e.g. [rollup-plugin-alias](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-alias) to manage the exact location of the Vue file you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand it a bit better now. I am afraid that wrapping the path value with quotes did not make any difference, but I will mark it as the correct answer. I spent 2 days on this and ended up just running rollup using the command line and automating everything in package.json scripts.